# The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.3.

And now I should find memory leak but I get an error

> The diagnostic tools failed

when I try use diagnostic while debugging.

I already restarted Visual Studio Standard Collector 150 service. I already uninstalled VS 2017 (I thought it can reason). I reinstalled VS 2019. And changed language. Nothing helped me.

Comment: There are a number of issues here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search.html?f=&type=question+OR+problem+OR+idea&type=question+OR+problem+OR+idea&c=&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=The+diagnostic+tools+failed+unexpectedly+vs2019

Comment: The first issue is My )